# Ruby 1.8 and disk I/O in a multi-threaded setting

Tags: ruby, multithreading, disk, nonblocking

> Ruby 1.8 uses userspace threads, not operating system threads. This means that Ruby 1.8 can only utilize a single CPU core no matter how many Ruby threads you create.
>
> On the bright side, not all is bad. Ruby 1.8 **internally uses non-blocking I/O** while Ruby 1.9 unlocks the global interpreter lock while doing I/O. So if one Ruby thread is blocked on I/O, another Ruby thread can continue execution. Likewise, Ruby is smart enough to cause things like sleep() and even waitpid() to preempt to other threads.

The above is an excerpt from a recent [blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/06/09/does-rails-performance-need-an-overhaul/) by the Phusion folks.

**How does MRI handle disk I/O internally?**

From what I gather, doing disk I/O in a non-blocking manner via select/epoll/kqueue is not possible since the `fds` will always be readable/writeable. So I would expect MRI to block when it does file I/O, but if it blocks there's no point in writing a multi-threaded program. Does MRI have an internal thread-pool to which these blocking I/O calls are offloaded to?

Comment: If you know C, this might be helpful to read: http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c

Answer (score 2):

Yehuda Katz, one of the core contributors to Rails 3, has blogged about this in some detail:
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/14/threads-in-ruby-enough-already